# Changes in Mongoose pre-save hook is not reflecting in db

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am updating the value of a mandatory field `procedureid` in mongoose pre-save hook. However, this is not reflecting in my MongoDB.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
const collection = 'hospital_doctor_details';
var hospitalDoctorSchema = new Schema({

    Treatment: [{        
        procedureid: { type: Number, required: true},        
    }],
    updated_at: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
});


hospitalDoctorSchema.pre('save', function (next) {

    var self = this;
    var treatmentcnt =parseInt( this.Treatment.length)-1
    self.Treatment[treatmentcnt].procedureid= 1234;

   next();

});

//create collection.
module.exports.hospitalModel = mongoose.model(collection, hospitalDoctorSchema);
```

Comment: In schema you've defined `procedureid` then why are you inserting `departmentId` in pre save ?

Comment: Sorry.That was a typo error while copying a few important code snippet from a big model.Question is corrected now.

Comment: When creating the obj do you pass `[{procedureid: "something"}]` or nothing? Because in case of nothing it should throw error, as `Treatment` doesn't exist yet. It would be helpful if you tell what exactly are you trying to achieve. There might be a better solution for that.

Comment: procedure id is a unique auto generated number.Whenever admin insert a new procedure,it creates a new unique number and assign to procedureid.As it's created internally by server side code,[{procedureid: "something"}] is not passed from controller,rather i prefer to generate automatically during every api call

Comment: Treatment is an array. So you mean to say whenever you create (or update later) it should insert a new object with new procedureid?

Comment: yes.Initially definition for procedure id was procedureid: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true, dropDups: true, default: 10000 },.As i want a unique number i want defualt value to be generated by a function.In order to achieve it i have used pre save hook.Ideally iam looking for procedureid: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true, dropDups: true, default: functioncalToGenerateUniqueNumber}

Answer (score 0):

In `preSave`, you're trying to access an array which, what I understand from your comments, does not exist at the time of creation. You therefore need to assign empty array to `Treatment` and then push an object containing `procedureid`.

```
hospitalDoctorSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.Treatment = this.Treatment? this.Treatment : []; 
    this.Treatment.push({
        procedureid : 1234
    });
   next();
});
```

This will push more objects to `Treatment` array on subsequent saves (`find` and `save`), which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct.However somwhoe procedureid  is not reflecting in db using the above codesnippet

Comment: preSave should be in model or controller?

Comment: In the model, exactly where you have placed in the question.